# How do I translate my code from console app code in VS2019 to Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, windows-forms-core

I have already made an console app in visual studio 2019 in c# and everything is working.
Now I have to make in work in Windows Form in Visual Studio.

If I for an example have an function to print a list of animals how do I convert it so the list is printing when pressing a button?

A teacher said that I was suppose to copy the code I have class by class from my Console applications Program.cs to Program.cs in windows form.

So I have done all that , but how can I print the generated list with a button click?

replies will be grateful

Comment: What do you mean by "print a list"? Display it in a TextBox? Or a ListBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest reading up a bit on how UI systems work in general, and winforms in particular. For example this [Textbox tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-textbox-control-in-windows-forms-application-using-visual-stuudio-2/)

When using an UI you need a Control for the text to be displayed in, like a [textbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=net-5.0). This has a Text-property that can be set to to display your text. Note that you will probably need to configure your textbox for multiline text.